# Mac terminal problems

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, yeoman

I recently switched over from windows pc to mac for development and i´m looking for some help regarding the terminal.

When i try to install compass wich is a ruby gem, i´m met with this error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

Is there a way for me to execute gem installments etc without doing sudo?

I found out that this "sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local" worked for npm. Now im looking for a way to do the same with ruby and yeoman.

Comment: Have you installed `rvm` (or other Ruby version manager)?

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have pointed out, it is recommended that you try to use `rvm` or its cousins, to install `ruby` into your home directory, this way, you dont need root to install gems by default, and this is more widely **recommended**.

Alternatively you could try the same `chown` trick here

try

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<username> /Library/Ruby/Gems
```

The second one is usually group name, it can be skipped, or you can let it stay.

Comment: I would recommend `rvm` (or perhaps `rbenv`), unless OP has good reason not to use it.

Comment: Don't chown the Library directory. It's changing Apple's installed Ruby. Use RVM or rbenv instead. It's a lot safer.